# preg_match allow letters and numbers but at least 1 letter

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have the following preg_match statement that allows an input to be either letters a to z and numbers 0 to 9 only and it must be between 5 and 30 characters in length.

However, how would I also make sure that the input is not all numerics?  For example it must contain at least 1 a to z letter?

```
if (preg_match ('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\'.]{5,30}$/i', $str['user'])) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote you have a regex that *allows an input to be either letters a to z and numbers 0 to 9 only*, but actually `^[a-zA-Z0-9\'.]{5,30}$` matches a string of 5 to 30 ASCII letters, digits and also `'` or `.`.

If you just want to make your regex match what it matches, but not a string that only consists of digits, use a `(?!\d+$)` lookahead:

```
'/^(?!\d+$)[a-z0-9\'.]{5,30}$/i'
   ^^^^^^^^
```

Note you do not need to specify the `A-Z` or `a-z` range if you use a `i` case insensitive flag (just either of them is enough).

The `(?!\d+$)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if there are one or more digits followed by the end of string (`$`) immediately to the right of the current location (which is the start of the string).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbReaZ/1).

If you do not want to match a string that only consists of dots, or `'`, or digits, use

```
'/^(?!(?:\d+|([\'.])\1*)$)[a-z0-9\'.]{5,30}$/i'
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbReaZ/2).